# CSS vertical align an image with text not working (Wordpress)

Tags: css, image, wordpress, html, vertical-alignment

So I'm trying to get an image file to be vertically aligned in the middle of a div with text on the right hand side on my mobile Wordpress theme. Unfortunately, using a "vertical-align:middle" on the image results in the following:

[image]

Here's my CSS:

```
        <div <?php post_class('post clearfix'); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <div style="vertical-align:middle"><?php if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) : MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail('post', 'secondary-image');  endif; ?></div>
<h2 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'themater' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
             <div class="postmeta-primary-fp">

           <?php echo get_the_date(); ?></div>

               <div class="postmeta-primary-fp"> <?php if(comments_open( get_the_ID() ))  {
                    ?><span class="meta_comments"><?php comments_popup_link( __( '<b>0</b> comments', 'themater' ), __( '<b>1</b> comment', 'themater' ), __( '<b>%</b> comments', 'themater' ) ); ?></span><?php
                } ?>
        </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Make a parent div to hold the image and text, put the image in a left floated div, with line-height set to the height of the div, and vertical-align set to middle, then add a right floated div for the text. Something like:

```
<div style="width:400px;">
    <div style="float:left;width:50px;height:50px;line-height:50px;vertical-align:middle;">
        <img src="imageurl" />
    </div>

    <div style="width:380px;float:left;height:50px;">
        Text here
    </div>
</div>
```

And if you want the text aligned center to the image, set its line height equal to the div height, and vertical align to middle.